# Planning algorithms in WSN

Tags: dijkstra, planning

I'm looking for some planning algorithms that i can use to collect informations from sensor nodes in WSN. I found Dijkstra Algorithm but the problem with it is that it can't go through all the given nodes. I need 3 algorithms for my test.

Comment: This question is not complete. What are you looking for? What did you try? See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i'm looking for an algorithm that calculate the shortest path in a graph and it has to pass by ALL the nodes in this graph.

Comment: You are looking for [Hamiltonian path problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem)